# Convergence of a sequence problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume that the sequence $a_n$ converges to $l$. Let $b_n = a_{n+1}/n$. Show that $b_n$ converges to the same $l$.

> Since $a_n$ converges to $l$, for any $\varepsilon> 0$, there is a natural $N$ such that
>   if $n ≥ N$, then $|a_n − l| < \varepsilon$. Note that if $n ≥ N$, then $n+1≥ N$ and $|a_{n+1} − l| < \varepsilon$ as well.
>   That is, if $n ≥ N$, we have $|b_n − l| < \varepsilon$. This proves that $b_n$ converges
>   to l as well.

I found this proof in a book but I modified $b_n$ from $b_n =a_{n+1}$ to $b_n = a_{n+1}/n$ and now I am stuck. What do I do about the $1/n$ the $m$.

Comment: Please use LaTeX for readability.

Comment: I don't understand why you modified the definition of $b_n$. With the modified definition  $b_n \to 0$, not to $l$.

Comment: The result is totally false. It should be obvious why.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question. Actually, if $a_n$ converges to a real number $l$, and $b_n = a_n/n$, here is a proof that
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = 0$$

Solution 1. We have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = l$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n=0$. Use the multiplication rule, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n= l \cdot 0= 0$$

Solution 2. $\forall\epsilon>0$. Since $a_n$ converges to $l$, there exists $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N_0$, $|a_n-l|<l$. Let $N=\max\{\lceil\frac{2l}{\epsilon}\rceil,N_0\}$. Thus, for all natural number $n>N$ (which implies $n+1>n>N\ge N_0$)
$$0<a_{n+1}<2l$$
multiply by $1/n$ to both side of the inequality,
$$0<\frac{a_{n+1}}{n}=b_n<\frac{2l}{n}<\frac{2l}{N}\le\epsilon$$
Therefore, $\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\in\mathbb{N} (n>N\Rightarrow|b_n-0|<\epsilon)$, which means $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = 0$.